# Error while trying to create index.html under /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache

Tags: apache, unix, chef-infra

I am getting an error (see below) while trying to create index.html under

`/root/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache`

How can I fix this?

"Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/var/www/html/index.html"

```
 -----> Existing Chef installation detected
172.31.17.94 Starting the first Chef Client run...
172.31.17.94 Starting Chef Client, version 13.7.16
172.31.17.94 resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apache"]
172.31.17.94 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
172.31.17.94   - apache (0.1.0)
172.31.17.94 Installing Cookbook Gems:
172.31.17.94 Compiling Cookbooks...
172.31.17.94 Converging 4 resources
172.31.17.94 Recipe: apache::default
172.31.17.94   * yum_package[httpd] action install (up to date)
172.31.17.94   * service[httpd] action start (up to date)
172.31.17.94   * cookbook_file[/var/www/html/index.html] action create
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     ================================================================================
172.31.17.94     **Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/var/www/html/index.html]'
172.31.17.94**     ================================================================================
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound
172.31.17.94     ------------------------------
172.31.17.94     Cookbook 'apache' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
172.31.17.94       files/amazon-2017.09/index.html
172.31.17.94       files/amazon/index.html
172.31.17.94       files/default/index.html
172.31.17.94       files/index.html
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     Resource Declaration:
172.31.17.94     ---------------------
172.31.17.94     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache/recipes/default.rb
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94      14: cookbook_file '/var/www/html/index.html' do
172.31.17.94      15:  source 'index.html'
172.31.17.94      16:  owner 'root'
172.31.17.94      17:  group 'root'
172.31.17.94      18:  mode  0755
172.31.17.94      19:  action :create
172.31.17.94      20: end
172.31.17.94      21:
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     Compiled Resource:
172.31.17.94     ------------------
172.31.17.94     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache/recipes/default.rb:14:in `from_file'
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     cookbook_file("/var/www/html/index.html") do
172.31.17.94       action [:create]
172.31.17.94       default_guard_interpreter :default
172.31.17.94       declared_type :cookbook_file
172.31.17.94       cookbook_name "apache"
172.31.17.94       recipe_name "default"
172.31.17.94       source "index.html"
172.31.17.94       owner "root"
172.31.17.94       group "root"
172.31.17.94       mode 493
172.31.17.94       path "/var/www/html/index.html"
172.31.17.94       verifications []
172.31.17.94     end
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94     System Info:
172.31.17.94     ------------
172.31.17.94     chef_version=13.7.16
172.31.17.94     platform=amazon
172.31.17.94     platform_version=2017.09
172.31.17.94     ruby=ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
172.31.17.94     program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=26049;start=04:43:09;
172.31.17.94     executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94
172.31.17.94 Running handlers:
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
172.31.17.94 Running handlers complete
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
172.31.17.94 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] ERROR: cookbook_file[/var/www/html/index.html] (apache::default line 14) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound: Cookbook 'apache' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
172.31.17.94   files/amazon-2017.09/index.html
172.31.17.94   files/amazon/index.html
172.31.17.94   files/default/index.html
172.31.17.94   files/index.html
172.31.17.94 [2018-02-07T04:43:11+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are requesting `source 'index.html'` but there is no `index.html` file under the `files/` directory in that cookbook. Perhaps you meant to use a `template` resource instead?